# How to insert, delete, update data on aws s3 (json/csv format) to aws elasticsearch service

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3

I am setting data ingestion from aws s3 to aws elasticsearch service.

The incoming data will be json or csv format, and it needs to be

1. inserted if elasticsearch does not have any record for id column
2. delete from elasticsearch and insert new record if id is already present in elasticsearch

These files can come into s3 at anytime during the day, as soon as file comes elasticsearch needs to be updated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logstash to watch your s3 buckets using https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-s3.html and output into your elastic cluster?

In your logstash pipeline you´ll need to check each incoming data for json or csv format and convert it according to your elasticsearch index mapping.

The insert or update functionality can be archievied by explicitly setting the _id for each document.